# Mongoose {unique:true} validator not working properly

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to catch the mongodb 11000 error in my test application when two emails are both the same, but each time the newly created user is added to the database and I am not seeing the error logged to the console. I am new to the mongodb,express stack in general, so I may be missing something obvious.

I am only receiving the following error in mongod:

```
background addExistingToIndex exception E11000 duplicate key error index: database.users.$email_1  dup key: { : "asdf@gmail.com" }
2014-06-02T01:52:34.654-0400 [conn10] index build failed. spec: { v: 1, unique: true, key: { email: 1 }, name: "email_1", ns: "database.users", background: true } error: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index: database.users.$email_1  dup key: { : "asdf@gmail.com" }
```

Here is the defined Schema:

```
//*****************************************
//Define User Schema
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    fullName: String,
    email: {type: String, unique:true},
    password: String,
    createdOn: Date
});
//Define User Model
mongoose.model('User',userSchema);
//*****************************************
```

Here is the code to enter it into the database

```
exports.doRegistration = function(req,res){

    User.create({

        fullName: req.body.register.fullName,
        email: req.body.register.email,
        password: req.body.register.password,
        createdOn: Date.now()

    }, function(err, user){

        if(err){

            console.log(err);
                    if(err.code===11000)
                          res.redirect( '/error );

        }else{

            console.log('success');
        }

        res.redirect('/');

    });
}
```

Comment: The validation does not happen on creating an object instance but on `.save()`. Only when it actually violates a unique index constraint on the collection is it possible to detect a duplicate. Look at the [`.save()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save) method in the API documentation.

Comment: Yes, I am calling `.create`which creates the objects and saves it. It returns an error object if one occurred and the object which has been successfully saved to the database to the callback. I have created duplicated entries in the database which contain the same `email` and the validation does not produce an error. Maybe I do not understand you completely...

Comment: @Nikita Did you resolve this? I am having the same issue only with user.save.  Mongoose validation gets ignored and mongo throws E11000 error crashing the server before the error can be handled. Point being mongoose validation should stop it before mongo ever needs to throw the 11000 error.

Comment: I wish I could help you, but I haven't touched node.js or mongo.db for quite a while now; so I'm not too familiar with that ecosystem at the moment.